# Table width border cellspacing cellpadding all 0 in HTML5 error validation

Tags: html, css, web

I need to use tables for some data but I am changing everything to HTML5 and new CSS. The problem is that those HTML5 validators are giving me validation problems with my tables

Here is my table

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="200"  align="left" valign="top"> TD 1 must be 200px width </td>
    <td width="200"  align="left" valign="top"> TD 2 must be 200px width </td>
    <td width="200"  align="left" valign="top"> TD 3 must be 200px width </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried some CSS but cannot make it to work. What I need is to have a table 600px width, 1 TR and 3 TD, each TD must be exactly 200px (600px / 3 = 200 each )

Tested adding style="align:left; valign:top;" but it does not work. Neither the cellspacing or cellpadding. Need no cellspacing no cellpadding no border but I don´t know how to achieve it ...

Any ideas?

Looked some info online but I only see new way of CSS to add collapse or something but I cannot really understand how to do without any spacing or padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid all those attributes with

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 600px;
}

table td {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left
}
```

and write a simpler markup

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>TD 1 must be 200px width </td>
    <td>TD 2 must be 200px width </td>
    <td>TD 3 must be 200px width </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVVEmw (border inserted just for clarity purpose)

---

As you can see every cell is automatically 200px wide
[image]

Comment: Thanks Fab. Just a small thing. How about each TD using exactly 200px? Also I need to add border:0px to table and what about cellpadding cellspacing?

Comment: Maybe I must set style to each TD to width 200px?